# Rest Assured Empty response body structure

Tags: java, json, rest, rest-assured

I'd like to test a find rest service, if I find smth I want to delete from the database, otherwise do nothing

I use it like this (where rs is the Response from find)

```
 JsonPath jsonPath = rs.getBody().jsonPath();
 Object foundName= jsonPath.get("name");

  if (foundName!= null) {

   expect().statusCode(200).when().delete("..." + foundName);

 }
```

So when nothing is found how to check the foundName for it , because I tried foundName!=null or foundName != "", and still it's not working.
So please explain what is the structure of an empty response body

Comment: In java you cannot compare strings with `!=`. Use the `String.equals("")` method

Comment: yes, I tried that as well and foundName.equals("") is false

Comment: Try using a debugger to find the value of `foundName`

Comment: I tried debugging and foundName has value ArrayList<E> with subelements : elementData = Object[0] (displayed value is []) , modCount = 0 , size = 0

Comment: So obviously it's not a string as you expected. Now you're a step closer to finding the error do you think you can work from here?

Comment: Well, I still don't know how to correctly check foundName, so I would appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 3):

Based on the debug info foundName is of type List , so the solution was to cast foundName to List and check if it's empty.

```
 List foundName = (List)jsonPath.get("name");
 foundName.isEmpty()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
rs.body(blankOrNullString());
```

worked for me to verify the response body is null or blank.

Answer (score 0):

You could call `jsonPath.getString("name")` which casts your (empty) response body to String and you could check it with `equals("")` (see [RESTassured JavaDoc](http://rest-assured.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.4.5/apidocs/com/jayway/restassured/path/json/JsonPath.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29)). I assumed that "name" is of type String.

Comment: I tried that it like that as well,  but jsonPath.getString() basicaly uses the same jsonPath.get() internally, so it's the same thing I tried with get()

Comment: I see. So what does the returned string contain?